# SQL - Insert NULL entry with Union then order by results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, union

Im trying to order a list of results by their description (not id) but i also need to insert another result with a null Id and description of 'ALL'.

To do this I use `UNION SELECT NULL, 'ALL'`

It should be a pretty simple query but i cant figure out how to insert 'ALL' before the query orders the actual result set.

Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    [dbo].[HouseType]
WHERE   [TypeId] = COALESCE(@TypeId, [TypeId])
UNION SELECT NULL, 'ALL'
ORDER BY [TypeDesc]
```

Ive also tried calling UNION SELECT before the results are ordered but it doesnt look SQL allows this.

```
UNION SELECT NULL, 'ALL'
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT      *
    FROM        [dbo].[HouseType]
    WHERE       [TypeId] = COALESCE(@TypeId, [TypeId])
    ORDER BY    [TypeDesc]
)types
```

Basically I want to see the following results (ordered):

1. ALL
2. Bungalow
3. Detached
4. Semi-Detached
5. Terrace

Comment: Problem is probably that you have more columns selected by wildcard `*` than you mentioned in you explicit select in UNION

Comment: Insert into a table. Insert the ALL then select from it and order result.

Comment: @GurV It gives me the following when using the second statement "The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified."

Comment: Since All sorts first the first should work.  Try actual column names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using another column:

```
SELECT  t.ID, t.description, 2 AS o
FROM    [dbo].[HouseType] AS t
WHERE   [TypeId] = COALESCE(@TypeId, [TypeId])

UNION ALL

SELECT NULL, 'ALL', 1 AS o
ORDER BY o, [TypeDesc]
```

This way `ALL` will *always* precede the results of your original query.

**Note:** As already noted in a comment there must be a match between the number and type of fields of the subqueries used in the `UNION` operation.

**Note 2:** As noted in the other comment by @A ツ using `UNION ALL` is always preferable over `UNION`, so use this instead when you have no worries about duplicate values.

Comment: Thank you Giorgos, whats your opinion performance wise between your answer and Zohars? it looks like it would be pretty minimalistic if any. Do you recommend using UNION ALL in this instance over UNION?

Comment: @Kendo I don't think it makes any difference performance wise using either of the two queries.  You can test both with your actual data and see how they compare. `UNION ALL` is *always* faster than `UNION` since the db engine doesn't have to look for duplicates when the former is used.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos Congrats on 50K !!

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Thank you! Looking forward to completing the next 10Κ!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for conditional sorting:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    [dbo].[HouseType]
WHERE   [TypeId] = COALESCE(@TypeId, [TypeId])
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, 'ALL'
ORDER BY CASE WHEN [TypeDesc] = 'ALL' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, [TypeDesc]
```

btw, I would suggest agains the use of `*` and explicitly specify the column names in the select list.
This is always best practice, espcially when using `UNION` - this query will raise an error if you ever add (or remove) a column from the `HouseType` table.

Comment: Thank you Zohar, i tried this solution but when i run it, it complains that "All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists." am i missing something? the table only contains 1) an id, 2) a description

Comment: It doesnt matter if you use * or select both columns it still happens with this answer.

Comment: Opps, that's due to the union. If it was union all it would not happen. editing my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try it in a subquery

```
SELECT *
FROM(
    SELECT  *
    FROM    [dbo].[HouseType]
    WHERE   [TypeId] = COALESCE(@TypeId, [TypeId])
    UNION 
    SELECT NULL, 'ALL')
ORDER BY [TypeDesc]
```

Comment: Funny how the only answer that is a. copy from the qustion, b. wrong and c. will not even compile is the one upvoted...

Comment: @ZoharPeled of course it's a partial copy from the question. I'm not trying to change OP's logic

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @HouseType TABLE (HouseType VARCHAR(30))
INSERT INTO @HouseType
SELECT      HouseType 
    FROM        [dbo].[HouseType]
    WHERE       [TypeId] = COALESCE(@TypeId, [TypeId])
    ORDER BY    [TypeDesc]

INSERT INTO @HouseType
SELECT 'ALL'

SELECT HouseType FROM @HouseType ORDER BY HouseType
```

Comment: Surely creating a temporary table is overkill for this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Assigns a Row to each TypeDesc using ROW_NUMBER function (+1 to go after the 'ALL') sorted by TypeDesc:

```
select 1 as [Row], 'All' as [TypeDesc]
union
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TypeDesc) + 1 AS [Row], [TypeDesc]
    FROM        [dbo].[HouseType]
    WHERE       [TypeId] = COALESCE(@TypeId, [TypeId])
ORDER BY [Row]
```

Comment: Hi!
It would be nice of you to provide some information about the code you are providing. Thanks!